# How to bind ListBox to a member of a view model in xaml?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I'm just starting with wpf/vmmv.  I've seen examples of binding collections to list boxes.  Example: in xaml , in code-behind  (e.g. Page)  "DataContext = collection.. ".

My view model has more properties than just a single collection that need to be bound to a view.  Therefore I'd like to set the view model as DataContext for the view and then, in xaml, bind the view model's collection to a ListBox.  Assuming that my view model is set as DataContext and it has a property called 'Customers', what is the correct way of binding the property to a ListBox in xaml?
I tried  but it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean 'how do you bind a collection to a 'ListBox'? You would do that like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

Or this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}" />
```

If you want to bind the internal values of each instance of the `Customer` class, you would do something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EyeColour}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>        
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You beat me to it, Nice one :)

Comment: Before asking the question I had tried ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" but with no success.  Your answer made me look back at the code and noticed that Customers property wasn't public.  Strange that I did not get any feedback but I guess that is expected.  Your example with DataTemplate will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display the property "Customers", what you have to do is define ItemTemplate of ListBox, define DataTemplate inside ItemTemplate, and binding Customers to a control, just like below:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Customers}"/>
            ......something else you want display
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```